# For loop through only a portion of a dictionary Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
[2, ["aaa", "bbb"]]
[10, ["ccc", "ddd"]]
[1, ["eee", "fff"]]
[9, ["ggg", "hhh"]]
[4, ["iii", "jjj"]]
[8, ["kkk", "lll"]]
...
```

I have a for loop that loops through the sorted (based on keys in ascending order) dictionary:

```
for i in sorted(dict):
     print "%s %s" % (dict[i][0], dict[i][1])
```

And the output should be:

```
eee fff
aaa bbb
iii jjj
kkk lll
ggg hhh
ccc ddd
...
```

However, the for loop right now loops through every single element. But if I only want to loop through, for example the first 4, how do I do that? The output is going to be:

```
eee fff
aaa bbb
iii jjj
kkk lll
```

I know there is this method called range, but this apparently doesn't work:

```
for i in range(4)
   print "%s %s" % (dict[i][0], dict[i][1])
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Initialize a counter before the loop, increment it with every iteration, and `break` when it's `4`.

Comment: Minor correction: that is not a python dictionary. But you surely already knew that ;)

Comment: The reason your attempt doesn't work is because `for i in sorted(dict)` iterates over each key, while `for i in range(4)` iterates over the numbers 0 through 4 (not including 4). It sounds like your dictionary keys don't include `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sorted()` returns a list of dictionary keys, so you can just iterate through a slice of the first four items:

```
for i in sorted(dict)[:4]:
     print "%s %s" % (dict[i][0], dict[i][1])
```

Also, in case you hadn't realised, you shouldn't use a [Python built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) name as a variable name else you'll lose access to the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
counter = 0

for i in sorted(dict):
    print "%s %s" % (dict[i][0], dict[i][1])
    counter += 1
    if counter == 4:
        break
```

Also, name your dictionary something other than `dict` so that you don't mask the built-in function `dict()`.

Comment: Would anyone like to explain the downvote so I can improve this answer?

Comment: `counter + break` is not at all Pythonic. See some of the other answers.

Comment: Using `break` with a counter is simple and clear. The other solutions are good, but I think this one is fine too.

Comment: You're using four lines of code to do a `[:4]`; that's a giant loss of readability even if it's "simple".

Comment: The upside is that it works for things that can't be sliced, like generators or `while True` loops. Since the OP didn't know any way to loop over only part of an iterable, it's a good strategy to at least be aware of.

Comment: For generators you should use `itertools.islice`. And if you're breaking on a loop counter, you don't really need `while True`, just use a `for`; that's what they're 'for' :).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
for (n, i) in enumerate(sorted(dict)):
    if n >= 4: break
    print("%s %s" % (dict[i][0], dict[i][1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just slice it. Also, looks way cleaner if you use the `items` methods and implicit unpacking:

```
for _, (a, b) in sorted(d.iteritems())[:4]:
    print a, b
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could fix your original code using [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange), which is similar to range, but uses lazy evaluation to minimize its memory footprint.

```
>>> di_sorted_keys = sorted(di)
>>> for i in xrange(4):
...     a, b = di[di_sorted_keys[i]]
...     print a, b
... 
eee fff
aaa bbb
iii jjj
kkk lll
```

The above code is efficient and scalable for large datasets and numerous queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `range` function as specified above, but you are using it wrong:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 4):
...     print ' '.join(sorted(x)[i][-1])
... 
eee fff
aaa bbb
iii jjj
kkk lll
>>>
```

Comment: This is terrible, you're sorting the whole dictionary each time.